# Postgresql use string_agg results in an IN statement

Tags: postgresql

Anyone know how string_agg results need to be "massaged" so they can be used in an IN statement?
The following is some sample code. Thanks for your time.
P.S: Before scratching your head and asking what the hell. I'm only using this code to show the problem of the string_agg b/c as you can see the query otherwise is a bit pointless.

Henry

```
WITH TEMP AS 
(
SELECT 'John' AS col1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Peter' AS col1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Henry' AS col1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mo' AS col1
)
-- results that are being used in the IN statement
--SELECT    string_agg('''' || col1::TEXT || '''',',') AS col1 FROM TEMP  


SELECT col1 FROM TEMP
WHERE col1 IN
(
SELECT  string_agg('''' || col1::TEXT || '''',',') AS col1
FROM TEMP  
)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `string_agg()` there? Just use `... where col1 in (select col1 from temp)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix dynamic code with static code. Your example is not very clear as to what exactly is it that you want to do. Your sample could be written as:

```
WITH TEMP(col1) AS (values ('John'), ('Peter'), ('Henry'), ('Mo'))
SELECT col1 FROM TEMP
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM TEMP)
```

or using an array:

```
WITH TEMP(col1) AS (values ('John'), ('Peter'), ('Henry'), ('Mo'))
SELECT col1 FROM TEMP
WHERE col1 = ANY (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT col1 FROM TEMP))
```

or simply (in this case since the main from and the subselect are the same table without any filters):

```
WITH TEMP(col1) AS (values ('John'), ('Peter'), ('Henry'), ('Mo'))
SELECT col1 FROM TEMP
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The purpose of the example is how to specifically use the results of a string_agg and then use those results in an IN statement. But it seems from your help that it is not possible. And that my next best option would be to use an ARRAY. But I'm kind of limited as the results of the end query actually get passed into a vb6 program as an IN statement. Of which can be considered a black box with no chance of modification.

Comment: @HenryMaher There is a way, but it is highly unreliable and would perform poorly, so it would be best suited as a last resort. `SELECT col1 FROM TEMP WHERE strpos((SELECT ','||string_agg('''' || col1::TEXT || '''',',')||',' AS col1), ','''||col1||''',') > 0`